# How to zoom to specific point in Highmaps

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

Highmaps / highcharts is a javascript/jquery adapter that renders maps in browsers etc.

I have a map with a single country highlighted, however, the scale of the (world) map is such that I want zoom in after the map is loaded on the country in question.

Looking at the API I feel certain this is possible.

There is an event listener, such that I can execute custom functions on load. As illustrated with this example, where a series is added on load ([Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/chart/events-load/))

Additionally there is a method `mapZoom` allowing you to specify a point to zoom to with the following arguments:

> mapZoom (Number howMuch, [Number centerX], [Number centerY], [Number mouseX], [Number mouseY])

But when I try and call this method onload (my code attempt below, JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8rgtuhbn/)), nothing happens.

```
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=world-population-density.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // Assign id's
        $.each(data, function () {
            this.id = this.code;
        });

        // Initiate the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                    mapZoom(0.5, 100, 100);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Zoom on load attempt'
            },


            legend: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Population density per km²'
                }
            },

            colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                max: 1000,
                type: 'logarithmic'
            },

            mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            },

            series : [{
                data : data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres'],
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                name: 'Population density',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{point.id} {point.name}',
                    valueSuffix: '/km²'
                }
            }]
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mapZoom` is a method that belongs to the `chart` object so, in order to call it as en event (`load`), you have to call it using `this` keyword.

You can edit your code like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rgtuhbn/1/)):

```
...
events: {
    load: function () {
        this.mapZoom(0.5, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
...
```

Alternatively, you can call it whenever you want using a jQuery reference ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rgtuhbn/2/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts().mapZoom(0.5, 100, 100);
```

Comment: How would you zoom in to a specific (lat,lon) location?

Comment: `var pos = this.fromLatLonToPoint({ lat: 51.5, lon: 2.0 });`
`this.mapZoom(0.1, this.xAxis[0].toPixels(pos.x), this.yAxis[0].toPixels(pos.y));`
is zooming in, but not to the required position

Comment: Hi, zooming in to x,y doesn't mean going to x latitude, y longitude. The map has a different coordinates system different than the geographical -90:90, -180:180. If you want to make the conversion, you will need to use the proj4 library. Please see this discussion: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/5780574-add-ability-to-plot-points-based-on-longitude-lati

Answer (score 5):

Zoom to a specific country on your map is easy

```
series : [{
            ...
            data: [{code: 'HU', id: 'HU', value: 7.5, name: 'Hungary'}],
            ...
            }
```

...and then...

```
var mapChart=$('#MapContainer').highcharts(); //get map chart object from DOM
mapChart.get('HU').zoomTo(); //zoom to the country using "id" from data serie
mapChart.mapZoom(5); //elevate viewpoint a little to see surrounding countries as well
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to zoom several countries, than you can try this

```
events: {
    load: function () {
    var mapChart = this;
    ['DE', 'HU', 'RO'].map(function(code){
        return mapChart.get(code);
    }).reduce(function(acc, current){
      // Set map bounds
      acc._minX = isNaN(acc._minX) ? current._minX : Math.min(acc._minX, current._minX);
      acc._maxX = isNaN(acc._maxX) ? current._maxX : Math.max(acc._maxX, current._maxX);
      acc._minY = isNaN(acc._minY) ? current._minY : Math.min(acc._minY, current._minY);
      acc._maxY = isNaN(acc._maxY) ? current._maxY : Math.max(acc._maxY, current._maxY);
      return acc;
    }).zoomTo(); 
 }}
```

Comment: I found your answer to working for zoom doesn't work accurately. do you know any changes required?